# get the row number from table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am new in iphone development, i am using table view to list name of the student, what i want to do is i want to get the row number of the cell the user pressed , currently i can get the name(string) of the cell,

//code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

//the obj.name where is a string, it works fine

```
obj.name=[obj.studentname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

//if i try obj.num , where num is nsinteger .i am getting errors of type i dnt understand

```
obj.num=[[obj.studentname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]count];
```

i even tried 
 but i cant get the number. example if faizan lies on 12th cell. what i want to do is,is save 12 in a number and show it on the next view label.i cant put it in the variable
thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` save the row number user pressed

```
int rowNumber = indexPath.row;
```

Comment: but than how do take it from one view to another

Comment: thats y i am trying to put it in ,obj.num , where num is a nsinteger

Comment: make the rowNumber as a property and then you can able to use it in another view.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  Your question is "how to get the row number of the cell the user pressed", which you're already doing:

```
indexPath.row
```

As for this very odd code:

```
obj.num=[[obj.studentname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]count];
```

You appear to be getting the name (as a string) from an array, and then you're trying to "count" the string, which you can't do.  You can get it's length:

```
[[obj.studentname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]length];
```

But that's not what you're asking for - what you're asking for you've already used in that expression!

Tim

Comment: my bad , about count. as i said i want to get the row number, as explained "if faizan is on the 12 cell, if user presses it than i should get 12 "

Comment: That's just indexPath.row as I said.

Answer (score 0):

@Trisha & @tarmes both are right. Maybe I can make it clear for you. :)

As the example you gave, I think the `obj` is your another view's object, and you want to set the name & number of range, right?

In your `.h` file, don't forget:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger num;
```

Then use it in other view controllers:

```
obj.name=[obj.studentname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
obj.num =[indexPath row] + 1; // if faizan lies on 12th cell, it saved 12([index cell]=11) in obj.num
```

You can treat NSInteger with int as the same, see NSInteger's declaration below:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
    typedef long NSInteger;
    typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
    typedef int NSInteger;
    typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to find the selected index.

```
  - (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
    {
        int idx=indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"Selected cell index:%i",idx);
    }
```